# Bool is not convertible to ObjCBool

Tags: objective-c, swift, boolean, ternary-operator

I'm getting this error doing :

```
return (index == self.pagesTitles.count || index == NSNotFound) ? nil : viewControllerAtIndex(++index)
```

**Bool is not convertible to ObjCBool**

I wanted to do a ternary operator for simplify the thing. Is there something wrong ?

Comment: What is the type of index? Why do you need to involve NSNotFound in this?

Comment: Try storing value in a `temp` variable, and then return it.
`let rValue = UTTypeConformsTo(utiCF, typeCF) != 0
 
rValue = (index == self.pagesTitles.count || index == NSNotFound) ? nil : viewControllerAtIndex(++index)
return rValue
`

Comment: I've tried it in Xcode-beta6 and it work.
`let index = 10 
let count = 20 
let result  = (index == count || index == NSNotFound) 
`

Comment: Supply more code. What type is `index`. What type is the method declared to return? A self-contained example is really best, something that can be copied and pasted into Xcode that demonstrates the problem. Debugging can require reducing the problem until the root cause is found. Also it is easier to resolve problem when there are several statements instead of one rather convoluted statement. Assigning to a variable and then returning the variable make debugging easier and the compiler will optimize that away.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you correctly specified the type of the returned object. In your case UIViewController?

```
func myMethod() -> UIViewController? {
    return (index == self.pagesTitles.count || index == NSNotFound) ? nil : viewControllerAtIndex(++index)
}
```